# How can I add eva icon to input ? Angular/Typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, icons

I am using nebular theme on my project. I am designing login page and I want to add eva user icon to the username input. But I couldn't put the inside of the input.

```js
<form #form='ngForm' class="mb-4" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)" aria-labelledby="title">
  <div class="form-control-group">
    <label class="label" for= "input-username">Username :</label>
    <input nbInput
           fullWidth 
           type="text"
           id="input-username"
           placeholder="Username"
           fieldSize ="large"
           #username="ngModel" 
           autofocus
           name="username" 
           [(ngModel)]="formModel.username" required
           [status]="username.dirty ? (username.invalid  ? 'danger' : 'success') : 'basic'">
        <ng-container *ngIf="username.invalid && username.touched">
        <p class="caption status-danger" *ngIf="username.errors?.required">
          Username is required!
        </p>
      </ng-container>
  </div>
```

[Nebular/Input with an icon](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/input/overview#nbinputdirective)

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes:

```
<nb-form-field>
      <nb-icon nbPrefix icon="at-outline" pack="eva"></nb-icon>
      <input type="text" nbInput>
</nb-form-field>
```

You can follow their documentation.

Comment: I forgot to add NbFormModule. I've realized now. Thanks anyway @Md. Shahidul Islam